# Is it possible to auto-bind BackboneJs view to existing element(s)?

Tags: backbone.js, view

I have a view:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({  
el: '.class-name',
events: {
    'hover .button' : 'test'
},
test: function() {
    console.log('hi');
}
});
```

Is it possible to have this view somehow automatically find all instances of '.class-name' on the page, and initialize itself for each - without me having to manually do it?

How is this usually handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, a view can't automatically initialize itself for multiple occurrences of matching `el` elements.

This is one way of doing :

```
$(".same-class").each(function(index,ele){
    var v=new MyView();
    $(ele).html(v.$el);
});
```

Method 2 :

```
$(".same-class").each(function(index,ele){
    var v=new MyView({el:$(ele)});        //non-tested
});
```